# Get Lon / Lat of a top left corner for geometry in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, coordinates, google-earth-engine

I want to extract latitude and longitude of a top left corner of a bounding box (**bbox**) for my geometry (**aoi**).

How do I do it in Earth Engine (preferably using server-side methods)?

I guess, it could be solved with some way of using `iterate()` over coordinate List's, but I failed to construct a valid way to do it.

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[103.6725886730469, 1.535723242616683],
          [103.5187800792969, 1.2117201436706377],
          [103.7494929699219, 1.1087444479525173],
          [104.1450007824219, 1.2309418499697466],
          [104.26173051875003, 1.5082671124456866]]]);

var bbox = aoi.bounds();
```

Comment: Since bbox is rectangle, this should work: `var coords = bbox.coordinates()`.

Comment: This still returns a nested list of - points - x,y, but the question is how to find min / max of that nested list?

Comment: I admit I've never used Earth Engine, but this nested list must have some inherent order from which you can deduce which element is top left corner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you do bounds on each geometry, you will have indeed a simplified rectangle on which you should do coordinates() to get a nested list of coordinates:

```
// return the list of coordinates
var listCoords = ee.Array.cat(bbox.coordinates(), 1);
```

Casting it to an array makes it possible to slice out the x and y coordinates:

```
// get the X-coordinates
var xCoords = listCoords.slice(1, 0, 1); print('xCoords', xCoords);
var yCoords = listCoords.slice(1, 1, 2); print('yCoords', yCoords);
```

Reducing each array reveals then the min and max values:

```
// reduce the arrays to find the max (or min) value
var xMin = xCoords.reduce('min', [0]).get([0,0]); print('xMin',xMin);
var xMax = xCoords.reduce('max', [0]).get([0,0]); print('xMax',xMax);
var yMin = yCoords.reduce('min', [0]).get([0,0]); print('yMin',yMin);
var yMax = yCoords.reduce('max', [0]).get([0,0]); print('yMax',yMax);
```

It works even on more complex geometries: [link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/00eeb84b38e315039ac28b8d93ac400c). If you have a feature collection, first get the geometry of the complete feature collection: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3ea2ab5cfb99bdd44d40515a8fec0f4e)